# Reading data from apache-pig into R

Tags: r, apache-pig

Is there any way for R to read data stored in apache-pig over a network? (Similar to how R can connect to a database over a network and access the data stored in the database.)

Alternatively, if this cannot be done, is it possible to "pipe-line" the data through java or python or any other language? Example: Java connects to Apache-Pig and R, allowing the data to move from Apache-Pig to Java to R.

Comment: take a look at http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-use-basic-pig-commands/ this tutorial reads in 2 files. I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I am looking for. I am look for a way to connect R to Pig over a network, similar to how R connects to a database, I'll add more info to the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `STREAM` command will work for you. Can you try from the below reference docs.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#stream
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#stream

I don't know R programming, so i tried with basic Ruby script and its works fine.

**input**

```
This is apache pig
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input';
B = STREAM A THROUGH `myruby.rb`;
DUMP B;
```

**myruby.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

STDIN.each do |line|
line.split.each do |word|
  puts word
end
end
```

**Output:**

```
(This)
(is)
(apache)
(pig)
```

Comment: The issue is that R is not installed on the node, i am using pig via a hortonworks sandbox vm, STREAM only works with local installation